# md-datepicker initial position

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I have troubles with md-datepicker.

initial position depends of the position of the field in the page.

I would like to display the same position for each field.

Here is an example :
http://jsfiddle.net/pwf66foq/

try the first and the last field, you will see the problem.
For the first one, the month of december is bellow
For the last field, you can't see the december month

Thanks for your help

Code :

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<h2>Focus on each input and press 'enter' to see its name</h2>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input name="address" 
        ng-model="address" placeholder="Address"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    <md-datepicker name="birthday" 
        ng-model="birthday" md-placeholder="Birthday"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    </md-datepicker>
    <p>input name: {{ name }}</p>
    <input name="address" 
        ng-model="address" placeholder="Address"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    <md-datepicker name="birthday" 
        ng-model="birthday" md-placeholder="Birthday"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    </md-datepicker>
    <p>input name: {{ name }}</p>
    <input name="address" 
        ng-model="address" placeholder="Address"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    <md-datepicker name="birthday" 
        ng-model="birthday" md-placeholder="Birthday"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    </md-datepicker>
    <p>input name: {{ name }}</p>
    <input name="address" 
        ng-model="address" placeholder="Address"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    <md-datepicker name="birthday" 
        ng-model="birthday" md-placeholder="Birthday"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    </md-datepicker>
    <p>input name: {{ name }}</p>
    <input name="address" 
        ng-model="address" placeholder="Address"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    <md-datepicker name="birthday" 
        ng-model="birthday" md-placeholder="Birthday"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    </md-datepicker>
    <p>input name: {{ name }}</p>
    <input name="address" 
        ng-model="address" placeholder="Address"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    <md-datepicker name="birthday" 
        ng-model="birthday" md-placeholder="Birthday"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    </md-datepicker>
    <p>input name: {{ name }}</p>
    <input name="address" 
        ng-model="address" placeholder="Address"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    <md-datepicker name="birthday" 
        ng-model="birthday" md-placeholder="Birthday"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    </md-datepicker>
    <p>input name: {{ name }}</p>
    <input name="address" 
        ng-model="address" placeholder="Address"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    <md-datepicker name="birthday" 
        ng-model="birthday" md-placeholder="Birthday"
        ng-keyup="checkName($event)">
    </md-datepicker>
    <p>input name: {{ name }}</p>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl ($scope) {

$scope.name = '';

$scope.checkName = function ($event) {
    console.log($event.target.name);
    $scope.name = $event.target.name;
};
}]);
```